# .Net SqlConnection class with Windows authentication

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell, windows-authentication

I'm using PowerShell System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class to create connection to my remote MsSQL server. Connection string looks like these:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server,$port; Database=$database; User ID=$software_user; Password=$software_password;"
```

That thing works fine, but I have to use Windows authentication to connect, not MsSQL internal account. The problem is, that Windows authentication don't have an option to specify which account will be used and it using same account as powershell.exe process.
Example: I have an account with name MyOrg\Someuser. I'm "Run as" Powershell exe as these user and now Windows authentication will try to use MyOrg\Someuser account to connect to MsSQL server

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server,$port; Database=$database; Integrated Security=True"
```

How can I specify a different account with Windows authentication without changing "Run As" user for Powershell.exe process? Specifying credentials with Integrated Security=True option doesn't work

Comment: You don't specify an account with Windows Authentication. You connect using *your* Windows account. That's the whole point, and what the name actually means. Why do you want to use Windows Authentication if you don't want to use the current account?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Explain the original problem that made you think of connecting using someone else's Windows account. Perhaps what you really need is to create eg a Scheduled Task using specific credentials. Perhaps you need SQL Server authentication instead of Windows Authentication. Perhaps you're trying to do something that's actually forbidden, like connecting to a domain server from a machine that isn't joined to the domain. In that case the server doesn't trust your machine and account. It only trusts domain accounts

Comment: My script is a part of program, which collect some info from MsSQL server. I have credentials, which is sent as arguments to my script and i have to use these credentials to connect with Windows authentication, not user which run the script. Both machines in the same domain

Comment: You're repeating the question, not explaining why you want to connect with another user's account. I repeat, the whole point of Windows Authentication is that you *don't* pass credentials. So why do you want to use another user's account? Why not add *your* account as a login to the server instead? Or run the script as under that other user's account?

Comment: This is usually painful to achieve in `.Net`. Did you try impersonating the account that's passed in and then create connection etc.

Comment: As i told, my script is a part of program and unfortunately I cannot change "Run As" user for my scripts, using sql server authentication is not the point coz i have to have both methods available as an options and i cannot ad "Run as" account to MsSQL server coz customer doesn't approve these. i can ONLY use credentials, which is sent to my script as arguments from "above" the program. These credentials are domain credentials and have enough rights for my business. The questions is how to open connection with Windows authentication in these situation

Comment: You can impersonate in code, no need to Run As

Comment: @siggemannen could u please give some example of what u mean? Coz it's not so clear for me to be honest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net Note that it might not work with sql server, cause in windows the default is: "Nothing works during impersonation unless someone spent time to make it work". Not sure also if there's a corresponding powershell code for that.

Comment: "i cannot ad "Run as" account to MsSQL server coz customer doesn't approve these" then it's not possible. You need *some* kind of impersonation, even if only doing it programatically. It's the same thing, just impersonation can happen without input from the user, if you store the password insecurely somewhere. Honestly I would recommend using Run As, that's what it's supposed to do, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Why not do the easy thing and add your account to the Group.  The SQL Database should be linked to a Windows Group.  In a Corporate Network it is usually Group Policy.  Then you do not have to impersonate.